# Should explained be 100% in PCA if the number of components is same as number of features?

Tags: variance, pca

I have a financial timeseries data with 13 features. When I apply PCA with n_components = 13, the explained variance doesn't sum up to 100%. My intuition was if n_components is same as the number of features, the explained variance should be 100%.

Under what circumstances, is it possible to have less than 100% explained variance if n_components = number of features?

Edited: The first 5 components explain 22% of variance and rest of the components don't add much value.

Comment: What does it add up to in your case?  One has to allow for floating point imprecision in these calculations.  Mathematically, what you report is impossible.

Comment: Re your edit: what you report is mathematically impossible (and cannot be attributed to floating point imprecision), because components are sorted by decreasing contribution to the variance, whence the top 5 out of 13 necessarily contribute *at least* 5/13 = 38.5% of the variance.